# How can I reuse an old user name?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, user-profiles

After upgrading from Windows 7 to Windows 10 Home my (local) user profile seems to be broken.
So I want to create a new local profile but using the old user name.
Therefore, I renamed the existing user profile (appended `_Win7`), renamed the user directory and changed the `ProfileImagePath` in the registry (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`).
The profile seems to run fine under the new name (despite the things that were already broken before the renaming).

Now the problem: **Windows doesn't let me create a new local user profile using the old profile's name**.
The error message is (translated from German): Enter a different user name.

How can I create a new profile using a former profile's name?

Comment: Did you rename the actual _user account_, or only the profile directory?

Comment: I renamed the user account as well, i.e. the login screen shows the new name for the old profile

Comment: If you go to This PC, right click it, properties (or control panel->system) and go to `advanced system settings`, tab `advanced`, `User Profiles`, does it list there correctly as well?

Comment: @LPChip No! It doesn't! It still shows the old name! So the questions is how to *really* rename the user account in Windows 10?

Comment: If you right click This PC, and choose Manage you'll go to `Computer Management`. From there, unvold `Local Users and Groups`, Click `Users`. Is the user here incorrect too? If so, right click and rename. If not, head back to the other window, click copy to copy to a new, then click delete to delete the old.

Comment: Is this Windows 10 Pro? The home editions of Windows don't allow the use of `lusrmgr.msc`.

Comment: It is the home edition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [LPChips comment](https://superuser.com/questions/997395/how-can-i-reuse-an-old-user-name#comment1377775_997395"), I found out that the user account wasn't *really* renamed using Windows 10 Home's system control panel. It was basically jsut the display name which was changed.
So I used `wmic useraccount where name='<OLDNAME>' rename <NEWNAME>` (found [here](http://www.windows-commandline.com/rename-local-user-account/)) to really rename the account and then I could create a new user with the old account name.